# How to Install desktop app installer from Get-ProvisionedAppPackage -Online in powershell?

Tags: powershell

```
Get-ProvisionedAppPackage -Online | ? {$_.PackageName -like "*DesktopAPP*"}
```

This command returns package details i.e its available but how to download and install it from within the powershell

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/add-appxprovisionedpackage?view=windowsserver2019-ps) link.

Comment: I piped the above command output to "Add-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online" but it doesn't work